# Usar un método que trabaje con objetos diferentes

Tags: c#, .net, revisión-de-código

Tengo un sistema que maneja muchos tipos de roles de trabajadores (alrededor de 30) en la empresa donde trabajo. Todos tienen datos en común (como datos personales). Lo que me gustaría eficientar es reutilizar código de método para muchos tipos de trabajadores. 
Algunos de las clases son: `Manager`, `Director` y `Employee` cada uno debe chequear su hora de entrada y eso lo hago con otra clase llamada `Company`, entonces tengo tres métodos para la clase:

```
public class Company
{
    public void CheckIn(Director Person)
    {

    }

    public void CheckIn(Employee Person)
    {

    }

    public void CheckIn(Manager Person)
    {

    }
}
```

Dependiendo el rol que entre en la empresa suceden diferentes cosas en los accesos de todo el edificio. Espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: Ya que no especifcas que código hay dentro de los métodos CheckIn he creado una respuesta que tiene varios ideas que te pueden servir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Claro que si, lo que puedes hacer es el uso de Interfaces. Las interfaces te permiten establecer reglas para las clases (atributos y métodos que de ley deben tener) Aquí un ejemplo de código:

```
public interface ICommonDataBetweenWorkers
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Identifier { get; set; }
    }

 public class Employee : ICommonDataBetweenWorkers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manager : ICommonDataBetweenWorkers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class Director : ICommonDataBetweenWorkers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public void CheckIn(ICommonDataBetweenWorkers Person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Person.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(Person.Identifier);

            if (Person is Manager)
            {
                //Do something
            }
            else if(Person is Director)
            {
                //Do something
            }

            else if(Person is Employee)
            {
                //Do something

            }
            /*
             * No importa si es manager, director o employee. Mientras implementan la interfaz
             * compartirán los mismos miembros.
             */
        }
```

Y cuando invoques tu método de checar entrada lo haces así:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Company C = new Company();

           //Cuando sea Employee
            C.CheckIn(new Employee());

            //Cuando sea Manager
            C.CheckIn(new Manager());

            //Cuando sea Director
            C.CheckIn(new Director());

            //Cuando sea otra cosa
            C.CheckIn(new OtherRoleThatYouHave());
        }
```

Comment: Vic, se me hace muy profesional tu estilo!

Answer (score 11):

Puedes usar una clase de herencia o un interfaz `Persona` donde todos los miembros comunes de todas las clases que mencionas lo contengan

Asi solo tendrias un metodo `CheckIn`:

```
public void CheckIn(Persona persona){

}
```

Por ejemplo:

Con interfase

```
interface IPersona
{

    string Nombre { get; set; }
    string Apellido { get; set; }
    DateTime FechaIngreso {get; set;}
    //un Largo etc.
}
```

[Nota sobre propiedades en interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/64syzecx.aspx)

Y con una clase

```
   public abstract class Persona { //puede ser abstracta o no
        string Nombre { get; set; }
        string Apellido { get; set; }
        DateTime FechaIngreso {get; set;}

        public void MetodoGenerico(){
        }
   }
```

De cualquier forma necesitas referenciarlas en los "hijos", en tu clase `Director` tendrías que tener

```
public class Director : IPersona //La I es por convención al usar Interfaces
```

o

```
public class Director : Persona
```

De cualquiera de las dos formas que elijas, agilizaras tu mucho desarrollo.

Comment: Esta me parece la mejor respuesta, las interfaces agregan claridad y hace  mas "mantenible" el código. No puedo dar +1 porque llegué al límite.

Answer (score 4):

Basado en que comentas

> Todos tienen datos en común (como datos personales). Lo que me
>   gustaría eficientar es reutilizar código de método para muchos tipos
>   de trabajadores

Además de la opción de uso de interfaces, tal vez basta utilizar alguna propiedad que te dé el rol de tu clase `Person`, por ejemplo `Person.Rol`, además de que puede haber un tipo de chequeado por rol, por ejemplo `CheckingType`, para agrupar los diferentes roles con comportamiento similar.

```
if (Person.Rol.CheckingType == Administrative)
{
//Turno administrativo
}
else if (Person.Rol.CheckingType == Supervisor)
{
//Turno gerentes/supervisores
}
else
{
//Los demás empleados
}
```

Comment: +1 Por exponer un punto que no habiamos mencionado, ni Victor ni yo ;)

Answer (score 4):

Dado que no especificas el código que está dentro de los métodos CheckIn voy a tratar de responder de las forma más general posible:

En primer lugar lo primero que debes intentra es crear una interfaz de los trabajadores que contenga los campos y métodos que deban ser comunes a todos. Por ejemplo:

```
public interface IRol
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int HoraMaximaDeLlegada { get; set; }
}
```

Luego cada tipo de trabajador puede implementar estos campos y métodos

```
public class Director: IRol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HoraMaximaDeLlegada { get; set; } 
}

public class Employee: IRol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HoraMaximaDeLlegada { get; set; } 
}

public class Manager: IRol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HoraMaximaDeLlegada { get; set; } 
}
```

De esta manera asumiendo por ejemplo que tenemos la siguiente clase

```
public class CheckIn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCheckIn { get; set; }
    public bool EsTarde { get; set; }
}
```

Tu método se podría reducir a:

```
public class Company
{
    public void CheckIn(IRol person)
    {
        // Acá puedes usar todos los campos disponibles en IRol para realizar la tarea que necesites
        // Ejemplo de implementación
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var checkIn = new CheckIn
        {
            PersonId = person.Id,
            FechaCheckIn = now,
            EsTarde = now > DateTime.Today.AddHours(person.HoraMaximaDeLlegada)
        };
        //... Hacer algo con ese nuevo checkIn
    }
}
```

Pero esto no siempre es posible.

Que pasa si no puedes modificar las clases por algún motivo de modo que no puedes hacerlas implementar de la misma interfaz. E incluso que pasa si las clases no tienen los mismos campos?

Esto se puede solucionar con el patrón [Adapter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o))

Este patrón es utilizado para cambiar la "interfaz" (término usado de manera genérica, no como `interface` de C#) de la clase que necesitas para adaptarla a una API en particular

Digamos por ejemplo que tenemos las siguientes clases:

```
public class Director
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Al ser el director no tiene una hora maxima de llegada
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HoraDeEntrada { get; set; } 
}

public class Manager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PuedeLlegarHasta { get; set; }
}
```

En este caso podemos crear un adapter que estandarice la interfaz

```
public abstract class BaseRolAdapter : IRol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract int HoraMaximaDeLlegada { get; set; }

    public BaseRolAdapter(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Y luego podemos crear un subitpo por cada Rol

```
public class EmployeeAdapter : BaseRolAdapter
{
    public readonly Employee Employee;

    public override int HoraMaximaDeLlegada
    {
        get { return Employee.HoraDeEntrada; }
        set { Employee.HoraDeEntrada = value; }
    }

    public EmployeeAdapter(Employee person)
        : base(person.Id)
    {
        Employee = person;
    }
}

public class ManagerAdapter : BaseRolAdapter
{
    public readonly Manager Manager;

    public override int HoraMaximaDeLlegada
    {
        get { return Manager.PuedeLlegarHasta; }
        set { Manager.PuedeLlegarHasta = value; }
    }

    public ManagerAdapter(Manager person)
        : base(person.Id)
    {
        Manager = person;
    }
}

public class DirectorAdapter : BaseRolAdapter
{
    public readonly Director Director;

    public override int HoraMaximaDeLlegada
    {
        get { return 24; /* Con esto el Director nunca llegara tarde */ }
        set { }
    }

    public DirectorAdapter(Director person)
        : base(person.Id)
    {
        Director = person;
    }
}
```

Donde cada implementación puede tener su propia lógica

Luego la clase `Company` quedaría así

```
public class Company
{
    public void CheckIn(BaseRolAdapter person) // o IRol en lugar de BaseRolAdapter  si implementaba la interfaz
    {
        // Acá puedes usar todos los campos disponibles en IRol para realizar la tarea que necesites
        // Ejemplo de implementación
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var checkIn = new CheckIn
        {
            PersonId = person.Id,
            FechaCheckIn = now,
            EsTarde = now > DateTime.Today.AddHours(person.HoraMaximaDeLlegada)
        };
        //... Hacer algo con ese nuevo checkIn
    }
}
```

De esta manera puedes hacer que el método CheckIn siempre dependa de una única clase o interfaz y no tener uno por cada tipo de empleado.

De todas maneras estas solo son algunas ideas, tu caso puede variar considerablemtente pero la idea es la misma, estandarizar la interfaz para poderla hacer única para todo tipo de clases.

Answer (score 3):

Para respectar los conceptos `SOLID`, no deberías usar ningun if o swith que aplique lógica segun la persona que debes validar.

Por eso se me courre plantear algo como esto

```
public abstract class Person {

    public virtual void CheckIn()
    {
        //implementacion por defecto de la validacion
        //usas el "this"" para hacer referencia al objeto
     }

}

public class Director: Person
{

    public override void CheckIn()
    {
        //implementacion para el director
        //usas el this para hacer referencia al objeto
    }

}

public class Employee: Person
{

    public override void CheckIn()
    {
       //implementacion para el empleado
       //usas el this para hacer referencia al objeto
     }

}

public class Manager: Person
{
   //este hace uso de la implementacion base
}

public class Company
{
    public void CheckIn(Person person)
    {
       person.CheckIn();
    }

}
```

Como veras con la herencia puedes hacer que la clase implemente su validacion concreta.
Lo invocarías de esta forma

```
Company company = new Company();
company.CheckIn(new Director());
```

En este caso use un `virtual` para definir una implementacion base, asi solo debes sobreescribir cuando es necesario, pero sino lo quieres asi podrias definir un metodo como `abstract`

Comment: Para este caso en particular no estoy de acuerdo de usar esta estrategia, por un simple motivo, `CheckIn` se codifica varias veces, cuando lo correcto seria que solo estuviera una ves en una clase de servicio ya que parece dificil que `CheckIn` tenga una logica diferente por rol. Y en el caso que plantea @Elvira parece mas que Persona y las demas clases son POCOS.

Comment: @jasilva, recuerda que mencione que si la logica es similar para varios casos con el virtual la defines en la clase base y no la tienes que definir en cada clase derivada. Lo que no entendi es porque mencionas una clase de servicio ? entiendo que se esta pensando trabajar orientado a objetos, ya que se quiere evitar definir metodos con cada sobrecarga, haciendo la aplicacion extensible segun los principios SOLID

Comment: Si estoy totalmente de acuerdo con eso, pero esa logica parece que no aplique al metodo `CheckIn` quiza el metodo `Despedir`. Donde para un usuario mortal sea un simple insert en una tabla y un update en otra, para Director se conecte con un web service de la CIA donde manda su fotografia y datos para que lo tengan vigilado. Se vea mas beneficiado de esta estrategia, ya que la logica es diferente, y es muy conveniente tener una comun y sobreescribir las excepciones :)

Answer (score 1):

Quiero agregar mi respuesta, aunque sugiero (como los demás) utilizar una interface en el objeto, sin embargo otra opción sería la siguiente:

```
    private void CheckIn(object person)
    {
        if (person is Director)
        {
            // lógica 1
            return;
        }

        if (person is Manager)
        {
            // lógica 2
            return;
        }

        if (person is Employee)
        {
            // lógica 3
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception("No es de un tipo aceptado por la función.")
    }
```

Saludos y [aquí tienes la referencia a "is"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Comment: Pero no estarias repectando los conceptos SOLID, especialmente el de abierto/cerrado

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @LeandroTuttini con que no se respeta ese concepto (O), por eso sugerí usar una interfaz para que cada uno de ellos realicen la misma tarea con lógica propia. Pero quizá sea una opción más a las otras.

Comment: Esta buena esa simplicidad!

Answer (score -1):

También se puede utilizar una definición de una clase con parámetros genéricos

```
public EmpleadoCompany<T> where T: ICommonDataBetweenWorkers
{
   public metodo1(T empleado1)
   {
      .....
   }

....


}
```